# How to replace an entire Pandas DataFrame row if all values equal np.NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nan

Example Code & Output:

```
data_country1 = {'Country': [np.NaN, 'India', 'Brazil'],
                 'Capital': [np.NaN, 'New Delhi', 'Brasília'],
                 'Population': [np.NaN, 1303171035, 207847528]} 

df_country1 = pd.DataFrame(data_country1, columns=['Country', 'Capital', 'Population'])

data_country2= {'Country': ['Belgium', 'India', 'Brazil'],
                'Capital': ['Brussels', 'New Delhi', 'Brasília'],
                'Population': [102283932, 1303171035, 207847528]} 

df_country2 = pd.DataFrame(data_country2, columns=['Country', 'Capital', 'Population'])

print(df_country1)
print(df_country2)

  Country    Capital    Population
0     NaN        NaN           NaN
1   India  New Delhi  1.303171e+09
2  Brazil   Brasília  2.078475e+08

   Country    Capital  Population
0  Belgium   Brussels   102283932
1    India  New Delhi  1303171035
2   Brazil   Brasília   207847528
```

In the first DataFrame, for *every* row that is comprised of **ALL** `NaN`, I want to replace the entire row with a row from another dataframe.  In this example, row `0` from the second dataframe, so that the first df ends up with the same information as the second dataframe.

Comment: Can we assume that the countries occur in `df_country1` in exactly the same order as in `df_country2`? Can we assume that the two data frames have exactly the same number of rows?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the rows that have `NaN` for all elements, and replace them with the rows of the other dataframe using:

```
# find the indices that are all NaN
na_indices = df_country1.index[df_country1.isnull().all(axis=1)]

# replace those indices with the values of the other dataframe
df_country1.loc[na_indices,:] = df_country2.loc[na_indices,:]
```

This assumes that the data frames are the same shape and you want to match on the missing rows.

Answer (score 0):

I will join the two dataframes:

```
data_complete=pd.merge(df_country1.dropna(),df_country2,on=['Country','Capital','Population'],how='outer')
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work as required: the answer states that only those rows from  `df_country1` should be replaced by the corresponding row from `df_country2`  where *all* columns are `NaN`. This code will replace a row from `df_country1` if there is *any* `NaN` in that row.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them using append, drop any duplicates (rows that were in both data frames), and then remove all the indices where the values are NaN:

```
#combine into one data frame with unique values
df_country = df_country1.append(df_country2,ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()

#filter out NaN rows
df_country = df_country.drop(df_country.index[df_country.isnull().all(axis=1)])
```

The ignore_index flag in append gives each line unique indexes so that when you search for the indexes with NaN rows and it returns 0 you don't end up deleting the 0 index row from df_country2.

Comment: This still doesn't quite work. If `df_country1` contains one or two values other than `NaN` in row 0, this row will not be considered a duplicate, so `df_country` will contain four rows in total.

Comment: Can you give me an example data set that demonstrates this?

Comment: Sure: `df_country1a = pd.DataFrame({'Capital': {0: 'Brussels', 1: 'New Delhi', 2: 'Bras\xc3\xadlia'},  'Country': {0: pd.np.nan, 1: 'India', 2: 'Brazil'},  'Population': {0: pd.np.nan, 1: 1303171035.0, 2: 207847528.0}}, columns=['Country', 'Capital', 'Population'])` (this is  `df_country1` with `Brussels` as the capital in the first row).

Comment: If you want rows to be considered a duplicate if the Captitol column is the same you can do it by adding this argument to `drop_duplicates`:
`subset='Capital'`  The problem there is that then it will drop one of the two and it might drop the row with more data.

Comment: I think what you are asking for is more of a merge instead of an append.  The original question doesn't ask this.  It only points out that you need to combine two lists and remove rows containing all NaN types, there is nothing about incomplete rows needing to be merged.

Comment: Merging is more complicated because what if there is a conflict... where two lines have the same Capitol but different Population numbers.

Comment: I'm not the OP, so I can only interpret this part from the original question: "*In the first DataFrame, for every row that is comprised of ALL NaN, I want to replace the entire row with a row from another dataframe.*" I believe what is meant here is that if the row is **not** "*comprised of ALL NaN*", i.e. if there is any non-`NaN` in the row, nothing should happen, i.e. more merge, less append. But only the OP would know (who doesn't seem to care too much about his question any more).

Comment: I read the original question as "_How do I combine these two data frames and then remove the row(s) that contain only np.NaN_"  I inferred that combine meant that he would want to remove any duplicate rows.